# Using all CPUs on CENT OS to run a c++ program

Tags: centos, openmp

Hi and thanks for the help. I have been running a program that has many functions with for loops that iterate over 10000 times. I have been using "#pragma omp_set_num_threads();" to use all the CPUs of my CENT OS device. This seems to work fine for all functions i have in my program except one. The function it doesnt work on is something like this:

```
void move_check()//function to check if "molecule obj" is in space under consid
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < NM ; ++i)//NM-no of "molecules"
    {
        int bounds;
        bounds = molecule_obj.at(i).check(dom_x,dom_y,dom_z);
        ////returns status of molecule
        ////molecule is a class that i have created and molecule_obj is an obj of that class.

        if(bounds==1)
        {
            molecule_obj.erase(molecule_obj.begin()+i);
            i -= 1;
            NM -= 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Can I use pragma for this? If not what other alternative do i have?
As the above function is the one that seems to be consuming the most time, i would like to utilize all the CPUs to execute it. How do i go about doing that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's all about the details. What you posted is incomplete/nonsensical since you'd never have that `if` inside the loop as it is.

Comment: @Mat, I'm sorry about the earlier post. Did not realise details were too few. Could you please help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle you can use an OpenMP pragma, just add

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

before the for loop.

You have to make sure that it is save to use the methods of your `molecule_obj` in parallel. I cannot know if they are but I assume the following:
`molecule_obj.at(i).check(dom_x,dom_y,dom_z);` really works with one specific molecule and does depend any others. That is fine than.

But the `erase` function most likely is not, dependent on how you store the entries. If you use something like `std::list`, `std::vector` erasing an element during the loop would lead to invalid iterators, wrong trip counts, etc.

I suggest that you replace the removal of the entry in the loop by just marking it for removal. You can add a special flag to each molecule for that.
Then after the completion of the parallel loop you can go over the list once in serial and actually remove the marked entries.

Just another suggestion: make a clearer distinction between one molecule and the list of molecules. It would improve the understandability of your code.